# Looking for function to shorten the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, wxpython

Some widgets in wxPython has a method like "GetSelections()" which returns a list of indexes of selected items.
Having this list of index I can get a list of items. This way, for example:

```
>>> list_of_items = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
>>> list_of_indexes = [1,3,5]
>>> [list_of_items[e] for e in list_of_indexes]
['one', 'three', 'five']
```

So the question is: is there a shortcut for last string? Something like:

```
list_of_items.getitems(list_of_indexes)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few approaches you can use.

#### List slicing

Replace `[1, 3, 5]` with an equivalent [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object:

```
list_of_items = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
list_of_indexes = slice(1, 6, 2)

res = list_of_items[list_of_indexes]
```

#### Itemgetter

If you need to supply a list which cannot be represented by `slice`, you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list_of_items = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
list_of_indexes = [1, 3, 5]

res = itemgetter(*list_of_indexes)(list_of_items)

print(res)

('one', 'three', 'five')
```

#### Numpy

3rd party library `numpy` supports your desired indexing syntax directly:

```
import numpy as np

list_of_items = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
list_of_indexes = [1,3,5]

res = np.array(list_of_items)[list_of_indexes].tolist()
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! "Slice" will be the new word in my python lexicon.

Comment: But... sorry that way: 
    list_of_indexes = slice(1, 6, 2) is not suitable for me, because I've got list of indexes from outside. I can't replace it with slice. 
Using Numpy is possible, but this is too much.